# Converting Microsoft Graph v4 to v5 problems

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to convert this block of code into Microsoft Graph v5 code but having an issue with it. What would the correct query parameter be for this for the select, as well as selecting the first user as shown in the previous code.

Here is the function:

private async Task GetGuestUserByEmail(string email)

```
private async Task<string> GetGuestUserByEmail(string email)

{
    try
    {
        string filter = $"proxyAddress/any(x:x eq 'SMTP:{email}')";
        var users = await _graphClient.users
                            .Request()
                            .Filter(filter)
                            .Select(e => new
                            {
                                e.DisplayName,
                                e.Mail,
                                e.UserPrincipleName,
                                e.EmployeeId,
                                e.Id,
                                e.OtherMails,
                                e.ProxyAddresses
                            })
                            .GetAsync();
                            
                return users[0].UserPrincipleName;
    }
    catch(ServiceException ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I tried something along the lines of this but I believe it is incorrect with the userResponse.Value.FirstOrDefault();

I'm not sure how to get the first ID like done in the previous version.

When I stepped through my code it did not reach the if statement.

```
private async Task<string> GetGuestUserByEmail(string email)

{
    try
    {
        
        var userResponse = await _graphClient.users
                            .GetAsync(requestionConfiguration =>
                            {
                                requestionConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string [] { "Id", "DisplayName", "UserPrincipleName", "Mail", "EmployeeId", "OtherMails", "ProxyAddresses" };
                                requestionConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = $"mail eq '(email)'";
                            }
                            );
                            

                            
                            
                var user = userResponse.Value.FirstOrDefault();
                
                if (user != null)
                {
                    string id = user.Id;
                    string displayName = user.DisplayName;
                    // continued assigning here
                }
                
                Return user.UserPrincipleName;
                
    }
    catch(ServiceException ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is an exception being thrown? What do you mean by "When I stepped through my code it did not reach the if statement."? If an exception is being thrown what is the message?

Comment: Try to catch ODataError instead of ServiceException, or in general, catch Exception and share details. You also have typo in UserPrincipleName => it should UserPrincipalName.

Comment: Do you have any update on this question? Pls kindly let me know if my post is helpful for you to solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

this line of code seems to have some issue. It can't read the value.

`requestionConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = $"mail eq '(email)'";`

Here's my test result.

```
string email = "mail@console.com";
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant_id";
var clientId = "client_id";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var users = await graphClient.Users.GetAsync();
var userResponse = await graphClient.Users
                .GetAsync(requestionConfiguration =>
                {
                    requestionConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "Id", "DisplayName", "UserPrincipleName", "Mail", "EmployeeId", "OtherMails", "ProxyAddresses" };
                    requestionConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = $"mail eq '{email}'";
                }
                );
var res = userResponse.Value.FirstOrDefault();
if (res != null)
{
    string id = res.Id;
    string displayName = res.DisplayName;
    // continued assigning here
}
return Ok("success");
```

[image]